# Has Amazon changed policy for getting MWS Access Keys?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-fba

I am trying to get Amazon Seller Access keys from User Permissions page and it says

"Developer Central
Are you a software developer building applications using MWS?
If you need MWS API Access Keys because you are coding software applications for your own selling account or to be utilized by other sellers, you can provide information about your business and apply for access here. We will thoroughly review your submitted information. This process may take up to 30 days. ".

in Past i used to see MWS access keys (access key and secret key) for a Seller but this is my 3rd time i am not able to see keys so my question is: Amazon changed their policy or some one can help me how we can get MWS access API Keys for a Amazon FBA Seller Account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, every seller with a pro account have MWS but if you wish to develop third-party system and access Amazon API, you will need to ask for Developer MWS Credentials.
After answering some questions about your need to use this MWS for development purpose, they with review and let you know (it takes about 30 days to get answer)

Comment: Yes correct and earlier mws api keys were just single button click generated now they have put more conditions to get mws api keys.... Thanks for the answer